# Colorize code after adding ASP.NET Core code

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code

Has it ever been considered to colorize the code in a post which is tagged with [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), etc. like the tag [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)?

<sub>(*Sorry if this is posted earlier, but I couldn't find anything about this.*)</sub>

Comment: If you want *language* syntax highlighting, then add a *language* tag. Otherwise, you'll have to add a manual highlighting hint. There is no other way for the syntax highlighter to know.

Answer (score 7):

ASP.NET is a library rather than a language. It can be used with any language that supports .NET (even though 99,9% of the time it's used from C#). So this tag alone does not prescribe the syntax to use.

Comment: This is probably downvoted because the wording is not entirely correct (asp.net is not just a library), but the point remains. We have [thousands of questions tagged asp.net and vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+vb.net), and if you feel like doing something weird you can work with ASP.Net using any .Net-compatible language, such as IronPython, F#, etc.. You can't add syntax highlighting for multiple languages, so asp.net certainly shouldn't get C# highlighting, because that would lead to the wrong highlighting.